# Acting with button in UICollectionView header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button called "Select" in my collection view header. How can I get section id in click-action of the button in order to iterate over cell elements in this section and mark them as selected?

Comment: Try looking at `UICollectionView`'s `indexPathsForSelectedItems`

Comment: This will give me index-paths of all selected items. But my problem is that I don't know how to get section id inside of click action callback. I need to have some data-binding between button and section, probably..

Comment: Does each section have its own header/button? If so, you could just assign a tag to each button that represents its section number

Comment: @LulzCow thanks. that worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You can add `func indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind kind: String, at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?` method in extension of `UICollectionView`

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind kind: String, at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath? {
        let targetRect = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
        guard let attributes = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect) else { return nil }

        return attributes.filter { $0.representedElementCategory == .supplementaryView && $0.representedElementKind == kind }.first?.indexPath
    }
}
```

and use this in your `UIViewController` for example like this

```
@IBAction func didSelectHeader(sender: UIView, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        guard let point = event.allTouches?.first?.location(in: collectionView) ?? sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: collectionView) else { return }
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: point) else { return }

        // do something with the indexPath
    }
```

the `indexPath.item` in our case is every time 0 but the indexPath.section is different, depending on the location of the header relative to the section of the `collectionView`